# What was Reb Moshe Feinstein's view on electricity use on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, electricity, moshe-feinstein

Did Rabbi Moshe Feinstein hold that the ban on electricity use on Shabbos (where no other issur results) is a biblical prohibition, a rabbinic prohibition, or just a minhag?

Comment: Maybe you mean Reb Zalman Oyerbach? he held that the issur is derabanan (minchas shlomo a, 9-12), so did the Tzitz Eliezer

Comment: As summarized [here](http://www.zomet.org.il/Eng/?CategoryID=198&ArticleID=283#a3) Rav Moshe did not come to a conclusion on the matter, and remained in doubt about it. I don't know the source enough to know if it is reliable, and I don't have time to check the quotes, but he gives his sources to investigate.

Comment: Rav Shlomo Zalmen held it was a minhag

Comment: @sam From wht I understand Reb Shlomo Zalmen did not hold it is a minhag but derabanan (issur "nolad" or "ovadin dechol")

Comment: Electricity can be used in various forms. For example a fan would have a different din than a light bulb. And a cell phone from a car. Every device and how they operate will determine what the din is

Answer (score 2):

He writes explicitly that he's not sure whether extinguishing an electric appliance is forbidden [*mid'oraysa*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/623), and uses that doubt as grounds, when combined with certain other grounds, to permit doing so. (*Orach Chayim* 3 #42.)

Comment: Which implies it is at least mid'rabbanan. +1