# What are the various views about electricity on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, electricity

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35474/9682) discusses specifically R' Moshe's views on using electricity on Shabbos. What are some of the other major views out there (R' Shlomo Zalman, Tzitz Eliezer, etc.)?

Believe it or not, there's actually a [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat) on the topic, though it just discusses the views of "many Orthodox leaders" without listing the specific views.

Comment: near dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12572/8775.

Comment: "though it just discusses the views of "many Orthodox leaders" without listing the specific views." Actually, numerous authorities are referenced there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_on_Shabbat#Range_of_practices, e.g. R. Yitzchak Schmelkes, R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, Hazon Ish, with numerous additional sources in the notes. It really seems to be what you are looking for. Along with the answers to [this near dupe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12572/8775) you will likely have more than enough.

Comment: @mevaqesh You are correct. I missed that question. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I didn't VTC yet is that that question only asks according to views that it is forbidden, whereas this one allows for views that it is not forbidden.